# Validating XML where element names contain sequence numbers

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm trying to create an XSD for validating XML we receive from our customer. The XML looks something like this:

```
<someElement>
   <items>
      <item1 name=”abc” />
      <item2 name =”def” />
      <item3 name =”ghi” />
   </items>
</someElement>
```

Note that for whatever reason the item names also contain a number. The number of items isn't specified and will vary by file.

Because of the line numbers in the element names something like this doesn't work:

```
<xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="items" type="item" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
</xs:sequence>
```

What would be proper XSD to validate this?

Comment: Just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299609/xml-schema-different-element-names-sequence, which unfortunately doesn't provide a suitable solution either.

Comment: How about running the original document through some XSLT which transforms `<item1 name="abc"/>` into `<item num="1" name="abc"/>`, and then validate that against a schema instead?

Comment: @matk I think @skaffmans suggestion is the best solution to deal mangled Xml like this. Your only other option would be to use `<xs:any />`.

Comment: @skaffman: I think your suggestion is the best so far... why don't you add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In previous cases where I've had to mechanically process badly-design XML, be it for schema validation or binding to a class model, I've found that pre-processing the XML with an XSL transform is often a good start. This pre-processing can in many cases turn badly-design XML into something nicer.

In your case, you could write a transform that turns

```
<item1 name="abc"/>
```

into

```
<item num="1" name="abc"/>
```

This is then much easier to design a schema for.  If a given XML input doesn't conform to that pattern, then the XSLT should leave it alone, and it will then fail validation.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid question: have you tried type="xs:string" instead of type="item"? I think you could get some inspiration using [this](http://www.xmlforasp.net/codebank/system_xml_schema/buildschema/buildxmlschema.aspx).

Comment: I've tried that generator already, but it also returns <xsd:sequence><xsd:element name="Item1" ...><xsd:element name="Item2" ...><xsd:element name="Item3" ...> etc.

Comment: Well, it tries to create the most restrictive schema possible, but you are free to edit it. Somehow, I'm not seeing the entire picture of what you're trying to achieve. Do you want "item" to represent a customized type that you declare in the XSD? What are the restrictions that you need for it? Do you want to make sure that the name attributes don't contain any numbers? That will be a bit tricky to achieve, but it can be done via RegEx: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/rnc/xsd.html#xsd-regex Maybe something like this: xsd:string { pattern='\D*' } (not tested!)

Comment: Well yes, but my question is _how_ to edit it :) What I want to do is simple, straight-forward XML validation. The example above was abstracted; the real item element contains fields such as part number, quantity, price etc. These are the ones I need to validate for existence, data type of the value etc. In an xs:sequence this would be straightforward, but I don't know how to handle the unique element names Item1, Item2... in XSD.

Comment: Oh, OK, now I understand. The thing is that the definition of a sequence is straight forward: a collection of specific nodes with a given tag name. Now, what you have there is, well, hard to define since, to my knowledge, you can't use recursion to define tag names in XSD. Also, I think that you need to ask the guy that produced that particular XML to learn the basics of XML design. Maybe the answer to this question provides more insight into this limitation of XSD: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821044/creating-multiple-element-name-with-sequence

Comment: Also, maybe you can use a XPATH selector to fetch those nodes, but, I'm unable to find a decent example: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_selector.asp

Comment: I'm fetching the nodes using the XPath {path}/items/*[starts-with(name(),'Item')], then validating them in code. While this works, it'd be a lot nicer to have XSD do the work for me.