# JAXB with similar elements and prefixed names

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Today, I tried to map the following structure with JAXB to Java code. The problem is, the XML structure is given and has the following drawback:

The object details data1, data2, ... are all the same for the different objects, so it would be very nice to create a super class. Unfortunately, the elements are prefixed with the names of the type dog, cat, ...

Is there an elegant way to map this with JAXB annotations, without code duplication?

```
<objects>
  <dog>
    <dog_data1>...</data1>
    <dog_data2>...</data2>
    <dog_data3>...</data3>
  </dog>
  <cat>
    <cat_data1>...</data1>
    <cat_data2>...</data2>
    <cat_data3>...</data3>
  </cat>
</objects>
```

Comment: See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548550/validating-xml-where-element-names-contain-sequence-numbers, it should help you here, even if the specific problem is different

Comment: Hi skaffman! I also thought about doing a XSLT transformation prior to the JAXB mapping. This would work and is probably the way to go, if there is no other solution. The problem with XSLT is, that it's far from elegant and it quickly can get very complicated. Furthermore we must also create these XML files, so a re-transformation would be needed.